# LateInitializationError: Field '_controller@24426303' has not been initialized. youtube_player_flutter

Tags: flutter

I am passing `String` from home to watch page and catching on watch before initiate `YoutubePlayerController` but seems like i am doing something wrong

here is my 2 methods

```
_getArguments(); //getting arguments from home page
_playYoutubeVideo(); // initiate controller for play initiated video
```

here both full function

_getArguments

```
Future<void> _getArguments() async {
    final widgetsBinding = WidgetsBinding.instance;
    widgetsBinding!.addPostFrameCallback((callback) {
      var currentVideo = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
      setState(() {
        _ids.add(currentVideo.toString());
      });
    });
  }
```

_playYoutubeVideo

```
Future<void> _playYoutubeVideo() async {
    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId: _ids.isNotEmpty ? _ids[0].toString() : '',
      flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
        mute: false,
        autoPlay: true,
        disableDragSeek: false,
        loop: false,
        isLive: false,
        forceHD: false,
        enableCaption: true,
      ),
    )..addListener(listener);
    _idController = TextEditingController();
    _seekToController = TextEditingController();
    _videoMetaData = const YoutubeMetaData();
    _playerState = PlayerState.unknown;
  }
```

and getting this error everytime `LateInitializationError: Field '_controller@24426303' has not been initialized.`

Comment: Instead of late you can try with null able like `YoutubePlayerController? _controller;`

Comment: here getting problem now `YoutubePlayer(
        controller: _controller,` error is `The argument type 'YoutubePlayerController?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'YoutubePlayerController'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your your controller (YoutubePlayerController) has not been initialized.

There are different solutions for this.

- Replace `late YoutubePlayerController _controller` by `YoutubePlayerController? _controller`, just make sure your controller is not null.
- Another solution can be adding a `void init()`, inside that you have to add `_controller = new YoutubePlayerController()`.

This error might occur due to a failed initialisation, make sure you initialize the controller before calling/rendering it.

Comment: `YoutubePlayerController? _controller` this break all code inside page
2nd i didn't understand

Comment: could you show the entire code?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/b8Hz8qP6